# The ample cone of a surface with an algebraic $\mathbb C^*$ action

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, ample-bundles

Let $X$ be a compact complex protective surface that admits a nontirvial algebraic $\mathbb C^*$-action. It seems to me, that the ample cone of $X$ is polyhedral with finite number of faces. I wonder if this is statement is correct and whether it is written down in some book/article.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is true, and follows from Corollary 3.29 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/0811.0517.pdf

Comment: Can you say something about *why* is it true, so that the reader will have the right idea prior to reading the paper?